# sencha architect production build : Uncaught TypeError: c is not a constructor

Tags: extjs, build, sencha-architect

I am having Extjs6 App. I am using Sencha Architect for UI . When I am building web using build setting , testing build was getting following error after build is done and onclick of my index.html.

```
  Uncaught Error: [Ext.createByAlias] Unrecognized alias: interaction.itemhighlight 
       at Ext.Inventory.instantiateByAlias (app.js:13520) 
       at Object.factory (app.js:7711) at constructor.applyInteractions (app.js:213699) 
       at constructor.setter [as setInteractions] (app.js:9056) 
       at constructor.addItemHighlight (app.js:206608) 
       at constructor.updateTooltip (app.js:206589) 
       at constructor.setter [as setTooltip] (app.js:9062)
```

Please help me to resolve this error.

Regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will be due to not requiring a class that you use, in development they are loaded dynamically.

To figure out what class is missing, you should run `sencha app build testing` which will not minify the code, and your error message will be more meaningful.

Comment: Hi Theo,
I was getting following error after doing sencha app build testing.
    Uncaught Error: [Ext.createByAlias] Unrecognized alias: interaction.itemhighlight
    at Ext.Inventory.instantiateByAlias (app.js:13520)
    at Object.factory (app.js:7711)
    at constructor.applyInteractions (app.js:213699)
    at constructor.setter [as setInteractions] (app.js:9056)
    at constructor.addItemHighlight (app.js:206608)
    at constructor.updateTooltip (app.js:206589)
    at constructor.setter [as setTooltip] (app.js:9062)

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar issue, the problem seems to be that sencha is not importing the library when is creating the production or testing builds, you should add the library you are missing in "**requires**" section of the view that uses it in this case i think the library is **'Ext.chart.interactions.ItemHighlight'** after this all your builds should work properly because sencha now knows that it needs this library in the build.
Sorry for my english, hope it helps.

Comment: What does your answer add to the question that the other existing answer did not?

Comment: the comment below the answer seems to imply that user1506628 is still having the problem, the answer provided by Theo  indeed helps to detect the problem, i just told how to solve the error, if my answer should have been a comment or maybe is not help at all, my apologies.

Comment: @z3ro You are right, When used Sencha CMD build production, testing some library not included will possible raise error